# FreeSwitch Verto module

Tags: webrtc, freeswitch

I'm following the section https://freeswitch.org/confluence/display/FREESWITCH/mod_verto to config module but having some points I didn't understand in topic.

Could you please help me explain?

> Dialplan
>
> To test if a call originated from a Verto client, test in
>   your dialplan for the variable Caller-Source to equal mod_verto in a
>   condition. There is also the variable Other-Leg-Source if the current
>   leg is using SIP or SS7 and the connected leg might be a Verto call.

```
<extension name="verto call" continue="true">
    <condition field="caller-source" expression="mod_verto">
        <action application="log" data="INFO ***** Verto WebRTC Call ***** "/>
    </condition>
</extension>
```

Where is these codes I will put? In conf/dialplan/default.xml?

> Bridging from WebRTC (mod_verto) to PSTN/ITSPs WebRTC is slow to
>   establish media. So we need to provide SDP asap. We can do this by
>   answering and sending some silent packets, instead of waiting for
>   normal call setup: Dialplan:

```
<extension name="itsp_send_call">
<condition field="destination_number" expression="^(\d+)$">
<action application="answer"/>
<action application="playback" data="silence_stream://2000"/>
<action application="set" data="effective_caller_id_number=333444555"/>
<action application="set" data="effective_caller_id_name=ciaociaociao"/>
<action application="bridge" data="{absolute_codec_string=pcmu}sofia/gateway/itsp/$1"/>
</condition>
</extension>
```

And these code too? Where should I put them?

Answer (score 0):

Those extension definitions can go wherever in your dialplan is necessary, it's the implementer choice.

This could be dialplan/default.xml - and if you're just starting out maybe that is the right place to put them.  But if your configuration is already having a more complex dialplan configuration they may go elsewhere.

These two references are **examples**.  The FS team is expecting you to decide where to put the examples - which you may need to modify for your specific environment.

In mine for example, I have the "verto call" extension early in my dialplan/default.xml - and have it also "set" some values and execute a webhook (see mod_curl)

I don't specifically use that *itsp* extension but modified that for my existing outbound gateway which I keep in dialplan/outbound.xml

Comment: Thanks @edoceo, I will try again with yours guide :)